# Cannot type a letter while in Bash in Cygwin

Tags: bash, unix, cygwin, alias

I am unable to type a certain letter while in bash.

I was editing .bashrc, or possibly .profile, which made it impossible to press the letter "a" (it is not showing up on screen, although I am able to type it in all other programs as usual.

I was trying to get aliases to work on my computer at the time, so it is possible that I somehow aliased `a` to `""`, although I am not sure how that would have happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by copying all the files in "cygwin\etc\skel\" (these are the backup starting files in case you ever need to replace them) into my home folder. You get to your home folder by tying "cd" and hit ender.